# Join or add to Spring Context

Tags: mysql, spring, join

I am working on a web application where optimization of speed is very important because a couple times a year it will operate at extreme capacity.

We have a bunch of tables we reference but two of the tables are small maps of abbreviations to descriptions like this :

bk = black, rd = red, drd = dark red, etc.

What we would normally do is join in the initial query of each small table to one or more much larger one(s) so that we can pass the value (description) to the front end instead of the abbreviation.

My thinking was that since none of the data in these tables has changed in many years we could save the minor but repeated cost of doing the join by loading them both into the backend application when it starts and add the appropriate value to the model as we send it to the front end.

I am far from an expert on Spring but I believe it has some sort of "application context" into which we could load this data and access it.

MY question is, would the join we would normally do be a more efficient way of doing this, because of the efficiency of how SQL does indexing and caching, or would it be better to load the data once and switch out the key and description after we do the query.

Comment: IMHO JOIN is fast enough if you introduce foreign key and indexes for the column.

Comment: So instead of a join and being able to parse the result in one go, you want to read everything into a map, for each record you read, consult the map (or cache or whatever) to get the translation. Instead of faster that might even be slower due to the additional complexity. IMHO this would be the last thing to try to optimize.

Comment: I would not call it "consult the map". You have a MAP, so you get back an object with a color property and you use the map to replace that abbreviations, so :

myBigObject.setColor(myColorDescriptionsMap(myBigObject.getColor()))